# Changing the value of a long array while eclipse debugging

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, debugging

I want to change the value and length of a long array during debugging.

For e.g. in my code

```
 long[] longArray = returnLongArray();
```

Now i want to change the value of longArray variable

the contents of longArray is [0,0,1,1] but i want to change it to [0,1,2]

please note that i want to change the contents of the long array as well as the length too and also hot swapping the code is not an option as the code is running on production

Through variables view i can go and change each primitive long value of the array but not able to reduce the length of the long array.

best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to change the value of the array object itself, to a value like "new type[4]", then edit the entries in the array and change their values also.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this, because you are not clear on which array items you are looking to delete.

Given:

```
longArray[0] = 0
longArray[1] = 0
longArray[2] = 1
longArray[3] = 1
```

or

```
longArray =  [0,0,1,1]
```

The array can be manipulated by:

```
longArray.splice(1, 1);
```

resulting in:

```
longArray =  [0,1,1]
```

The array can be manipulated again with:

```
longArray[3] = 2;
```

resulting in:

```
longArray =  [0,1,2]
```

Comment: there is no method in java as splice...and also the second approach you mentined will just change the value not the length

Answer (score 1):

This what i did .

I had to directly change the reference which was returned from returnLongArray();

I reduced the array length with longArray = Arrays.copyOf(longArray,3) and then change the values.